# yii2-mongodb синтаксис update c использованием $pull

Tags: yii2, mongodb, update

Доброго времени суток

Структура записи в коллекции:

```js
{
 "_id": ObjectId("577e3c801da29a8f2f8b4567"),
   "contacts": [
     {
       "id": NumberInt(7)
    },
    {
       "id": NumberInt(8)
    } 
  ],
  "user": NumberInt(8) 
}
```

Необходимо во всех записях удалить из массива contacts, объект с определенным id.

В Mongo задача решается таким запросом (для id = 7):

```
db.perimeter.update({ }, {$pull: {contacts: {id:7}}}, {multi: true})
```

Какой синтаксис реализации данной задачи средствами расширения yii2-mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

```
return $this->updateAll(
    [ '$pull' => ['contacts' => ['id' => ['$in' => $contactIds] ] ] ],
    [ 'user' => $this->user ]
);
```

Где $contactIds - массив id-шников для удаления объектов (с этими id) из contacts.